# HP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library when installing theme in Magento 2

Tags: themes, magento2

I tried to install this theme http://themeforest.net/item/luxury-premium-fashion-magento-theme/15345250 on magento 2, but this error comes when running the command

```
     bin/magento module:enable MGS_Mpanel
```

and the error is

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'/usr/lib/php5/20131226/php_intl.dll' - 
/usr/lib/php5/20131226/php_intl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No
such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'/usr/lib/php5/20131226/php_xsl.dll' - 
/usr/lib/php5/20131226/php_xsl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No 
such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Command line user does not have read and write permissions on 
var/generation directory.  Please address this issue before using 
Magento command line.
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows

Un-comment this line in php.ini file:

> extension=ext/php_intl.dll

for Ubuntu

```
apt-get remove php5-intl
```

or

```
pecl install intl
```

than restart apache